# Probability of having one pair in a poker hand

Tags: probability

Probability of having one pair in a poker hand?

ANS:  (13C1)x(4C2)  x (12C3) x(4C1)^3   x 1/(52C5)

Question:

> I interpret it as firstly choose 1 out of 13 face values, and then choose 2 cards out of the 4 face values. But my question is , why not just 4C13 to have a subset of 4 faces values; why do we have to 13C1 and then 12C3?

Comment: Somehow I find it hard to convince myself that the expression `ANS` is a number between 0 and 1, as a probability should be. Is there a typo?

Comment: yes, should divde the sample space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, suppose we do it your way and you choose the four ranks 2, 4, 7, K. Your first choice of two suits was $\heartsuit, \spadesuit$, and your other three suit choices were $\diamondsuit, \diamondsuit, \clubsuit$ in order.

What hand did you choose?

Comment: 2♡2♠, 4♢, 7♢, K♣,      so one pair

Comment: How do you choose the hand $4 \heartsuit, 4 \spadesuit, 2 \diamondsuit, 7 \diamondsuit, K \clubsuit$ then? Note that 2,4,7,K and 4,2,7,K are the *same* choice....

Comment: I think your point here is same as coffeemath. 13C4 will give 4 possible combination of ranks. But we need to specify which ones are the pairs.

Comment: @user3222184: Right! Also, I wanted to give a suggestion of the way I think about counting problems: I like to actually come up with algorithms for translating back and forth between the things I'm trying to count and the things I know how to count, which helps me set things up correctly and be sure that I actually have everything right.

Answer (score 0):

You can start as you suggest, with $4C13$ as the choice of which four ranks. After that you must choose which of the four ranks is to be the rank of the pair. So far this is $4*(4C13)=2860.$ In the given answer, the choices of ranks is $(1C13)*(3C12)=2860,$ the same thing. So either way gives the same count for the number of ways the ranks can be chosen, and once that is done the suits are easy to count as $(2C4)*(1C4)^3.$

So both approaches give the same final answer (provided one remembers to specify which of the four chosen ranks is to be that of the pair, in the second approach).